# Why AbsoluteThickness depends on ImageSize?

Tags: graphics, rendering, version-13

According to the Documentation ([second example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteThickness.html#353597015) under "Properties & Relations"),

> `AbsoluteThickness` is independent of the image size

Let us check (*Mathematica* 13.0.0 on Windows with 96 DPI display resolution, so I set `AbsoluteThickness[72/96]` in order to get a line of 1 px width):

```
Table[Image[
  ImageResize[
   ImageTake[ImageCrop@
     Rasterize[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[72/96], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
        PlotRange -> {{-is, is}, {-.1, 1.1}}}], ImageSize -> is], 10], Scaled@10, 
   Resampling -> "Constant"], Magnification -> 1], {is, 10, 300, 20}]

First /@ ImageDimensions /@ %
```

> [image: screenshot]

> ```
> {20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20}
> ```

Apparently, it depends on `ImageSize` in a strange and unpredictable way. Also, the color isn't always `Black` as it should be.

Let us check it with version 12.3.1 on the same machine (I set `AbsoluteThickness[1]`, because in this version 1 pt == 1 px):

```
Table[Image[
  ImageResize[
   ImageTake[
    ImageCrop@
     Rasterize[
      Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
        PlotRange -> {{-is, is}, {-.1, 1.1}}}], ImageSize -> is], 10],
    Scaled@10, Resampling -> "Constant"], Magnification -> 1], {is, 
  10, 300, 20}]

First /@ ImageDimensions /@ %
```

> [image: screenshot]

> ```
> {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20}
> ```

The line thickness is consistent but equals 2 px instead of 1 px, and the rendering of the line caps depends on `ImageSize` in an unpredictable way. Also, the color isn't `Black` as it should be.

And with version 8.0.4 on the same machine:

```
Table[Image[
  ImageResize[
   ImageTake[
    ImageCrop@
     Rasterize[
      Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
        PlotRange -> {{-is, is}, {-.1, 1.1}}}], "Image", 
      ImageSize -> is], 10], Scaled@10], Magnification -> 1], {is, 10,
   300, 20}]

First /@ ImageDimensions /@ %
```

> [image: screenshot]

> ```
> {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20}
> ```

Similar to version 12.3.1.

Is it a bug? How can I get consistent rendering with version 13?

Comment: After ""Rasterize"  the option "AbsoluteThickness[72/96]" is gone.

Comment: @DanielHuber What do you mean? After `Rasterize` we have `Image`, not `Graphics`. `Image` can't have any graphics directives, including `AbsoluteThickness`.

Comment: If you resize the image after rasterizing it, the absolute thickness is not retained.

Comment: The assumption that each line should render as one pixel thick is inaccurate, since it depends on the center of the `Line` primitive being center aligned with an element on the grid (in this case, a pixel).  Seeing that the FrontEnd works in a point-based coordinate system, the odds of your primitive aligning perfectly with the grid are not particularly favorable.

As for why it is not black, `Antialiasing`.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thank you very much! You can post it as an answer, and I'll accept it. With `Antialiasing -> False` I get consistent one-pixel thick rendering in all mentioned versions, and the line is `Black` as it should.

Comment: On Windows, there is another factor comes into play: the system-wise scaling factor. AFAIK, on modern laptop, Windows detects hi-res display and automatically suggests a non-100% scaling. On my laptop it's 125%, so I have `Lookup[SystemInformation["Devices","ConnectedDisplays"],"Scale"][[1]]==1.25*96/72`.

Comment: I did some investigation, but it's too lengthy to put here, so please refer to my [Wolfram Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2468048).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it becomes clear from the discussion in the comments, the cited Documentation statement isn't about *rendering* of the line primitives. It is about an abstract *vector* graphics scene, without any assumption about how it will be represented physically.

By applying `Rasterize` we *render* the abstract scene using some algorithm and obtain a discrete approximation of the original abstract vector object. Depending on the algorithm, the approximation can represent the features of the original more or less closely.

[Citing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262281/why-absolutethickness-depends-on-imagesize?noredirect=1#comment652978_262281) [ihojnicki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18638/ihojnicki),

> The assumption that each line should render as one pixel thick is
> inaccurate, since it depends on the center of the `Line` primitive being
> center aligned with an element on the grid (in this case, a pixel).
> Seeing that the FrontEnd works in a point-based coordinate system, the
> odds of your primitive aligning perfectly with the grid are not
> particularly favorable. As for why it is not black, `Antialiasing`. –
> ihojnicki

Apparently, by default we have antialiasing turned on for `Graphics` what is the reason for the effects demonstrated in the question. By turning antialiasing off we get consistent one-pixel thick `Line` rendering in all mentioned versions, and the color is `Black` as it should:

```
Table[Image[
  ImageResize[
   ImageTake[ImageCrop@
     Rasterize[Style[
       Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[72/96], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
         PlotRange -> {{-is, is}, {-.1, 1.1}}}], Antialiasing -> False], ImageSize -> is],
     10], Scaled@10, Resampling -> "Constant"], Magnification -> 1], {is, 10, 300, 20}]
First /@ ImageDimensions /@ %
```

> [image: output]

> ```
> {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}
> ```