# How can I create accurate image masks from Graphics?

Tags: graphics, bugs, image-processing, rasterize

I am looking to generate image masks using `Graphics`. For this, the requirements are that:

1. The rasterized mask must have the exact same dimensions as the image with which it will be used.
2. The image coordinates system (as described in the documentation of [`ImageValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageValue.html), under Details) must line up perfectly with the `Graphics` coordinate system.

Neither seems to work readily.

##### Mask has an incorrect size

```
dims = {20, 20};

mask = Rasterize[
  Graphics[{},
   PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, dims}], ImageSize -> dims,
   PlotRangePadding -> None
  ],
  ImageResolution -> 72
 ]
```

The `mask` is of the wrong size. `ImageDimensions[mask]` gives `{20, 22}`.

##### Coordinates don't line up

Example code:

```
dims = {21, 21};

pix = Image@ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, dims], {{11, 11}} -> 1]

mask = Rasterize[
  Graphics[{Disk[dims/2, 6]},
   PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, dims}], ImageSize -> dims,
   PlotRangePadding -> None
  ],
  ImageResolution -> 72
 ]
```

The image size is odd, so there is a middle pixel. `pix` visualizes this pixel. `mask` draws a disk around it. But the pixel is clearly not in the middle of the disk:

```
Magnify[mask + pix, 5]
```

[image]

##### Attempted workarounds

- `ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> None` does not help.
- Adding `ImageSize` to `Rasterize` as well, in addition to `Graphics`, does not help.
- `RasterSize` can force a specific image size, but it does not help with alignment

##### System information

Mathematica 13.0.1, [macOS 10.14.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave), and a retina screen

Comment: Use ```RasterSize -> dims``` instead? ImageSize for Rasterize is only the *display* dimensions…

Comment: I'm not really a fan of `RasterSize`. I suspect what it does is a rescaling _after_ creating an image. The `ImageSize` and the `ImageResolution` together should give a good result. The reason why I worry about such rescaling is that it might mess up the alignment between the image coordinates and the graphics coordinates.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Why AbsoluteThickness depends on ImageSize?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262281/280)"

Comment: Strongly related WC thread: "[Working with Graphics on Windows in a pixel perfect way](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2468048)."

Comment: I do not reproduce the first problem with version 13.0.1 on Windows 10 x64. `ImageDimensions[mask]` gives `{20, 20}` on my machine.

Comment: Would [`RegionImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionImage.html) be of use?

Comment: @Szabolcs Why do you suspect such a thing? I've never noticed that, and i *always* use RasterSize. Even the help of Rasterize says: ImageSize => final displayed image size in printer's points. (So only display!).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov The first problem can be reproduced in _v13.0.0_ Linux (Wolfram Cloud): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGMW.png

Answer (score 6):

The first behavior seems to be a bug of *v13*. In *v12.3.1* it works as expected:

[image]

As to the second example, this seems to be another bug introduced in *v12.3.1* or earlier, because *v9.0.1* works as expected:

```
$Version
dims = {21, 21};
pix = Image@ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, dims], {{11, 11}} -> 1];
mask = Rasterize[Graphics[{Disk[dims/2, 6]},PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, dims}]
    (*,ImageSize -> dims*), PlotRangePadding -> None], "Image", 
    ImageResolution -> 72, RasterSize -> dims];
(* mask + pix *)
ImageAdd[mask, pix]
```

[image]

For comparison here's *v12.3.1* result:

[image]

### Remark

1. I've removed the `ImageSize` option in `Graphics` and add the `RasterSize` option to `Rasterize`, otherwise the alignment will be wrong even in *v9*. (Yeah, once again, this seems to be a bug, in *v9*. )
2. I've used `ImageAdd` in *v9* because the syntax `mask + pix` is introduced in *v11.1*.
3. I've explicitly set the second argument of `Rasterize` to `"Image"` in *v9*, because the default setting before *v11.2* is `"Graphics"`.

Comment: I think the `PlotRange` is correct. For example, for a 1-by-1 image it should go from 0 to 1 when using `ImageValue` coordinates. But the centre of the `Disk[]` was indeed off. It should have been `dims/2`. I fixed that. I hope I did not make other mistakes. I'll check a couple of hours later.

Comment: It is interesting that uncommenting `ImageSize -> dims` in the above code in version 8.0.4 reproduces exactly the wrong alignment of version 13.

Comment: `Show[mask, ImageSize -> dims]` isn't needed in version 8 and its presence makes the whole comparison invalid because this piece of code converts `Image` to `Graphics` which at the next step is rasterized again to `Image`. I hadn't included this in my check with version 8.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov "because this piece of code converts `Image` to `Graphics` which at the next step is rasterized again to `Image`" This doesn't seem to be the case in _v9_ period. I just checked the `InputForm`, `mask` is a `Graphics[Raster[…],…]` expression, and after `Show[…]` the `InputForm` is still a `Graphics[Raster[…],…]` expression. It's a bit surprising that `ImageAdd[mask, pix]` works as expected in _v8_, because `ImageDimensions@mask` isn't `{21,21}` in _v8_ and _v9_, it's `{360, 378}`! I'm not sure if this is by design or another bug in v8/v9 period.

Comment: @xzczd Sorry, I forgot that in those versions `Rasterize` returns `Graphics` by default (but `ImageAdd[mask, pix]` really works as expected, probably by setting the appropriate `RasterSize` when rasterizing `Graphics`). For the comparison to be completely fair, we should use `Rasterize[Graphics[...], "Image"]` (but it returns the same output).

Comment: @Alexey Thx for pointing out, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think this regression bug is worth reporting to the support.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I guess they're monitoring the site? :) Still, I just sent a feedback.

Comment: @xzczd I wouldn't rely on the assumption that the WRI staff monitors the site. The only way to be sure that the support is aware of the problem is to send a report. And bigger weights are assigned to the problems reported by many people.