# Fine-tune width of lines in a plot, option like PlotWidth

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Is it possible to ***fine-tune*** the width of lines in a plot ?

There are ways to control the width of lines in a plot :

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "ThinLines"]
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "MediumLines"]
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "ThickLines"]
```

[image]

But it is far from fine-tuned.

Comment: The width of the ***plot*** (e.g. `ImageSize`) or the width of the ***lines*** in the plot (e.g. `Thickness[]` or `AbsoluteThickness[]`)?

Comment: Thickness. Sorry for not being accurate!

Comment: Related: [(262281)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262281/17), also [my Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2468048).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pixel size width add the option `PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3/4 * pw]`

Comment: Thank you, `PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[a number]` works well. But what does pw mean..? Present width ?

Comment: @imidak presumably, this would be a variable you set that describes the pixel size width or plot width of your lines. It would be useful to clarify what the `3/4` term represents, though.